# Show div on Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use a script that permits to show a div (with **class="result"**) on click of an **input type="submit" id="calc"** button.

Here's the codes:

**Google APIs and script**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#calc").click(function(){
        $("result").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

**Input type="submit"**

```
<input id="calc" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

**Div with class="result"**

```
<div class="result" align="center">
<form>
<textarea readonly="readonly" class="area" rows="6" cols="100" onclick="this.focus();this.select()"><?php
echo "<div style=\"width: 700px; padding: 10px; border: 5px groove #DD670F\"><p align=\"center\">[color=#DD670F][size=14]<strong>";
echo $title;
echo "</strong>[/size][/color]<br><br>";
echo "<img width=\"100%\" src=\"";
echo $img;
echo "\"></p>[color=#DD670F]<b>Titolo:</b>[/color] ";
echo "$title<br>";
echo "$seriesok $series $seriesbr";
echo "[color=#DD670F]<b>Autore:</b>[/color] ";
echo $autor;
echo "<br>[color=#DD670F]<b>Lingua:</b>[/color] ";
echo $language;
echo "<br>[color=#DD670F]<b>Tags:</b>[/color] ";
echo $tags;
echo "<br>[color=#DD670F]<b>Trama:</b>[/color] ";
echo $plot;
echo "<br><br>[color=#DD670F]<b>Image Preview:</b>[/color]<br>";
echo "[SPOILER]";
echo $imgpreview;
echo "[/SPOILER]<br>";
echo "[color=#DD670F]<b>Download Link:</b>[/color] [URL=";
echo $dllink;
echo "]<u>Download</u>[/URL]</div>";
?>
</textarea>
</form>
</div>
```

**On CSS**

```
.result {
  display: none;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You missed the `.` prefix for the class selector: `$(".result").show();`

Answer (score 2):

use below code

```
$(".result").show();
```

Use `.` selector for class element

> NOTE : if your button input type is `submit` then page will be redirect
>   to a other page or same page as per action set in form tag

use input type as `button`

```
<input id="calc" type="button" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But now code in textarea doesn't fill with variables that I've set.

Comment: That is other issue .. nothing is related to question you ask .. you need to check your php code

Answer (score 0):

Since it is class you are referring you should use `.` before `result`:

```
$("#calc").click(function(){
     $(".result").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#calc").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".result").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem solution is  replace this line

```
$("result").show();
```

to

```
$(".result").show();
```